# В Intellij Idea (Ultimate), в DataGrip не могу в меню найти пункт Import Data from File

Tags: intellij-idea, mongodb, datagrip

Хочу в **Idea**, в окне  **Database**, в коллекцию **mongodb** перенести данные из json файла. Судя по вот этой [статье](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-data.html)  в контекстном меню должен быть пункт **Import Data from File**. Но его нет. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть причина? Должен же быть какой-то импорт...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пункта нет, потому что импорт в Монгу не поддерживается:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-13643

Answer (score 0):

Потому что, необходимо кликнуть на папке "tables" или содержащейся в ней таблице:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет, дело не в этом. В mongadb вместо таблиц collection, и правый клик по ним не решает проблему, пункта Import Data from File - нет.